# Using this in the chunk callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, papaparse

I have a class which can parse a file using papa parse, now I would like to pass it a chunk callback function (which is also part of the class).

in the function i would like to use the this which should be pointing to the objects scope (but its pointing to the global scope)

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, you can use bind: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Also pay attention to call and apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

And of course ES6 arrow functions, that binds this to the current context

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: thank you for the fast response